# Similarity between arrays of cirteria's ratings

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dictionary dataset with many items and it's ratings for a fixed set of criterias (in example, 3 criterias):

```
item1 = { "Criteria1" : 5, "Criteria2" : 2, "Criteria3" : 1 }
item2 = { "Criteria1" : 0, "Criteria2" : 1, "Criteria3" : 5 }
item3 = { "Criteria1" : 4, "Criteria2" : 2, "Criteria3" : 1 }
```

I must find the best way to define the most similar items to a user item.
For example:

```
useritem = { "Criteria1" : 5, "Criteria2" : 2, "Criteria3" : 2 }
```

Could be result in:

```
similarity = { "item1": 0.95, "item2": 0.17, "item3": 0.91 }
```

Cosine's similarity is a way to achieve this? 
If so, i found scikit learn that do this in python. How can I transform the item's dictionary in a ndarray to use with cosine similarity?

Tks

Comment: You can use [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer) for making the dicts to features matrix of shape [n_samples, n_features] and then easily apply cosine_similarity on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes cosine distance is a good metric to find similar items, I believe it is the most used metric for recommender systems.

For the data structure, I would recommend using [pandas dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) to hold your dataset. It is easy to create, flexible and can easily be converted to numpy arrays (`df.values` will give you the inner numpy array).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[{ "Criteria1" : 5, "Criteria2" : 2, "Criteria3" : 1 },
          { "Criteria1" : 0, "Criteria2" : 1, "Criteria3" : 5 },
          { "Criteria1" : 4, "Criteria2" : 2, "Criteria3" : 1 }],
    index=["item1", "item2", "item3"])
```

Creates a dataframe as below.

```
       Criteria1  Criteria2  Criteria3
item1          5          2          1
item2          0          1          5
item3          4          2          1
```

And you can use any distance metric from sklearn using dataframes.

```
>> from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
>> cosine_similarity(pd.Series(useritem), df)
array([[ 0.98524468,  0.40967325,  0.98765833]])
```

Note: Using cosine similarity with a 1d array is deprecated so the code above will give you an error since useritem is `(3,)` shape. You can use `pd.Series(useritem).values.reshape(1, -1)` to reshape it to more appropriate `(1, 3)`.

Comment: Thanks @umutto. I have implemented your code and most of result makes sense. But there are some inconsistent results. For example, the criteria's values range is from 0 to 4. For a user_item (1,1,0) and (4,4,0) the given similarity is 100%. It makes sense for cosine similarity? What I expected was 100% similarity between (1,1,0) and (1,1,0) and something below 100% similarity between (1,1,0) and (4,4,0).

Comment: @paulofg yes it makes sense, cosine similarity only measures the angle between two vectors, ignoring their magnitude. This is intentional as cosine similarity is meant to capture content not the intensity. Think as this, `(1,1,0)` is just the scaled down version of `(4,4,0)`. But I see your point, your data is already scaled and you want to see a difference between bigger vectors, in that case you can use dot product of the vectors (simple, does same as cosine similarity except it includes magnitude) or other metrics like Jaccard (I believe it also uses magnitude) and see which fits you best.

Comment: before your answer I have checked the cosine similarity formula (yes, I should did this before ask :-) ) and realized that it's based on vector angle and direction. Looking at sklearn.metrics.pairwise api I found Bray–Curtis dissimilarity metric. In preliminary tests it has fit my data set with best results, even then Jaccard. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @paulofg glad I helped, and good on you for testing different metrics and finding the best fit. That's something a lot of people can't/don't do!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer) for converting the dicts to features matrix of shape [n_samples, n_features] and then easily apply cosine_similarity on it.

```
item1 = { "Criteria1" : 5, "Criteria2" : 2, "Criteria3" : 1 }
item2 = { "Criteria1" : 0, "Criteria2" : 1, "Criteria3" : 5 }
item3 = { "Criteria1" : 4, "Criteria2" : 2, "Criteria3" : 1 }

useritem = { "Criteria1" : 5, "Criteria2" : 2, "Criteria3" : 2 }

from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

vectorizer = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)

inputData = vectorizer.fit_transform([item1, item2, item3])
toCheckData = vectorizer.transform([useritem])

similarity = cosine_similarity(inputData, toCheckData)
# Output: similarity
  array([[ 0.98524468],
         [ 0.40967325],
         [ 0.98765833]])
```

Comment: Thanks @vivek-kumar. I have combined your suggestion with ummuto's answer and solved my problem using Bray–Curtis dissimilarity.